# can you force ActiveRecord find to include nil when associated record not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way to force :include in ActiveRecord find to output nil in results where conditions are not met?

For example if I have classes: Parent and Children. Parent has many childrens and I do something like this:

```
children_ids = [1,2,3]
my_parent = Parent.find(:all,
                        :include => :children,
                        :conditions => ['parent.id = 1 AND children.id IN (?)', children_ids])
```

Assuming that I have only childrens with id 2 and 3 statement:

```
my_parent.children
```

will return array with two childrens. But I would like to know which one they are (second and third in my children_ids array). So is it possible for :include to input nil for child that I'm missing?

If this description is too confiusing then let me know and I will try to present it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find out what records were missing, you can do it in rubyland by processing retrieved records.

```
retrieved_ids = my_parent.children.map(&:id)
unretrieved_ids = children_ids - retrieved_ids
```

Comment: It's not the solution I hoped for but it helps me to move on so thanks :)